# ggplot2: to reverse the order of dot so small values are bigger points, and larger values are small points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just got into R and have somethings going. 
I have been stuck at this problem for 2 days. Been through lots of web pages to fix my ggplots. I thought to ask here. The points with the lowest p value are small points whereas the points with large values (not so significant - not interesting) are bigger blobs. Its the small ones that I want to have sticking out as big and the big ones as small. I have p values that are pretty much 0. How can i reorder/adapt my code accordingly?  I have tried lots of variations. 
Any suggestions would be so very helpful.
Thanks so very much to everyone out there.

```
gg <- ggplot(mydata) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = celltype, y = reorder(pathways,number), size = pvalue, fill=celltype, color = celltype)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue")) + 
  labs(title="Reactome pathways enriched in subpopulations", y="Pathway enrichment")
```

Answer (score 2):

The typical solution in this kind of situation is to make a new variable that more directly represents what you want to plot.  Try adding `significance = 1 / pvalue` (or `1 - pvalue`, or whatever creates the sizes you want).

```
library(dplyr)
gg <- ggplot(mydata %>% mutate(significance = 1 / pvalue)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = celltype, y = reorder(pathways,number), size = significance, fill=celltype, color = celltype)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue")) + 
  labs(title="Reactome pathways enriched in subpopulations", y="Pathway enrichment")
```

Comment: Perfect! :) Thanks!!